# How to get "time" from ping url?

Tags: ios, ping

I want to get time from ping url like in terminal. I don't know how.

> 64 bytes from 123.30.53.19: icmp_seq=0 ttl=249 time=2.587 ms

Can you help me on this?

Comment: in Terminal in iOS ? what do you mean ?

Comment: no,I using X-code get time from url, run app on Iphone,ipad

Comment: you want ping result / reachability result ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: ping result as same as above code ,( i need time of url )

Comment: you may look up this library, https://github.com/chrishulbert/SimplePingHelper

Comment: i try with this library, but its display url is connection or fail, don't display time calculate by "ms"